# Use second pdfgrep find as a variable

Tags: bash, grep

I'm using pdfgrep to find certain information in a pdf and rename said file with that info. However, with dates, I need to format them in a different way than the file has saved. I'm planning on pulling each part of the date (month, day, year) as individual variables so that I can reformat them with if statements. Is there a way to store the second found number as a variable in bash?

```
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob

for f in *.pdf; do
    id1=$(pdfgrep -i "ID #: " "$f" | grep -oE "[M][0-9-][0-9]+")
    id2=$(pdfgrep -i "Second ID: " "$f" | grep -oE "[V][0-9-][0-9]+")
    # Check id1 is found, else do nothing
    if [ ${#id1} ]; then
        mv "$f" "${id1}_${id2}.pdf"
    fi
done
```

Rresults of command in terminal:

```
$ pdfgrep -i "Date of Birth: " 2.pdf | grep -oE "[0-9]+"
3
23
1977
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<(...)` process substitution to have the output of `grep` redirected into three `read` commands that store the values in separate variables.

```
{ read month; read day; read year; } < <(pdfgrep -i "Date of Birth: " 2.pdf | grep -oE "[0-9]+")
```

Result:

```
$ echo "$month-$day-$year"
3-23-1977
```

Comment: That works so well! Would you know of any easy way to add a leading zero to a day/month if it there's only one digit? (Ex. July 5th comes as just 5-7, but I need 05-07)

Comment: `printf '%02d-%02d-%04d\n' "$month" "$day" "$year"`

Comment: Looks good! I'm not the best programmer, so do you know how I would incorporate this in my existing code?

Comment: Use `$(...)` command substitution to use the output of `printf` as part of the new file name. Something like `mv "$f" "${id1}_${id2}_$(printf ...).pdf"`